How did Paul come to the conclusion that one flesh is sex?
In 1 Corinthians 6:15,16 Paul says
"Do you not know that your bodies are members of Christ himself? Shall I then take the members of Christ and unite them with a prostitute? Never!
Do you not know that he who unites himself with a prostitute is one with her in body? For it is said, 'The two will become one flesh.'"
But I still find it strange how one can BECOME one flesh. The way the sentence is worded doesn't give the impression that the author is talking about sex. It would make sense if it were "and they unite in one flesh". But hayah doesn't mean to unite.

Marriage is a union of person. In that estate there is also the union of flesh. The misuse of this human function causes disfunction on every level. It appears to me that that is what you are seeing in the verse. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of questions and answers as to how this plays out in practice. Welcome to SE-BH.

Hey Indigo! Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! We are glad you are here. If you get a chance, please take the  tour to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. Also consider going through the Help Center's  sections on asking and answering questions.

Most translations say "joins" rather than "unites," although this may be a distinction without a difference. In any case, Jews in general, especially Pharisees such as Paul, were very familiar with the Book of Genesis. This is the origin of the phrase "they will become one flesh."
Genesis 2

23 Then the man said,
“This at last is bone of my bones
and flesh of my flesh; this one shall be called Woman,
for out of Man this one was taken.”
24 Therefore a man leaves his father and his mother and clings to his
wife, and they become one flesh.

Becoming "one flesh" is a metaphor for sexual union in marriage. Originally Adam was to become "one flesh" with Eve to fulfill the blessing of Gen. 1:28 to "be fruitful and multiply and fill the earth." Paul contrasts the ideal meaning of "becoming one flesh" (in marriage blessed by God) with the abuse of sexuality by sinfully joining one's body with that of a prostitute.
